# Open CV - Python RGB to GRAY convertor

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, grayscale, computer-vision

I wanted to code this RGB to grayscale convertor without any inbuilt Open-CV function. This is how my code looks like

```
import cv2 , numpy
def GrayConvertor(img):


    rows , cols , layers = img.shape

    matrix = numpy.zeros((rows , cols))

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            val = 0.114 * (img[i][j][0]) + 0.587 * (img[i][j][1]) + 0.299 * (img[i][j][2])
            fraction = val - int(val)
            if fraction >= 0.5:
                matrix[i][j] = (int(val) + 1) 

            else: 
                matrix[i][j] = int(val) 
    cv2.imshow("gray" , matrix)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However it shows a blank image , Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create your `matrix` array with `np.zeros` it is, by default, assigned `dtype=float`. So even though you round and convert your values to `int`, when writing them into `matrix`they get stored as `float`s. If you read [the docs for `cv.imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) you will find the following:

> - If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are
>     multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to
>     [0,255].

So everything in your image is getting multiplied by 255, thus messing up your final result.

You can do two things:

1. Have a floating point `matrix`, skip all the rounding, and divide your values by 255.
2. Explicitly create your `matrix` with `dtype='uint8'` and leave everything unchanged.

There is also the fact that you are doing a very poor use of numpy's capabilities. The two options I gave you above, you can code with no loops or matrix assignments, as

```
rgb2k = np.array([0.114, 0.587, 0.299])
matrix_int = np.round(np.sum(img * rgb2k, axis=-1)).astype('uint8')
matrix_float = np.sum(img * rgb2k, axis=-1) / 255
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Had this thing bugging me for a long time , and did not know where to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import cv2 , numpy
def GrayConvertor(img):


    rows , cols , layers = img.shape

    matrix = numpy.zeros((rows , cols))

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            val = 0.114 * (img[i][j][0]) + 0.587 * (img[i][j][1]) + 0.299 * (img[i][j][2])
                matrix[i][j] = round(val) 
    cv2.imshow("gray" , matrix)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: i dont use Python. try converting to uchar before putting the value in matrix[i][j].